# C++ cross-compiling using cmake Qt5 Webkit on a Linux box, targeting Windows using mingw, fails

Tags: c++, cmake, webkit, qt5, mingw

First of all, it has been impossible for me to find an answer on google so far. I will try to describe as much as I can, I am seeking for advice on what I am doing wrong, be aware that I am in no way expert on this. My goal is to create a qt5 webkit window in c++ that will run on both linux and windows for a start. It compiles and works absolutely fine on linux but fails to compile for windows as you will see below. I will appreciate any kind of help on this, I am stuck.

> OS: Kubuntu 19.04
>
> Kernel: 5.0.0-21.22

The project tree is as follows

```
├── bin
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
├── platforms
│   ├── linux.cmake
│   └── windows.cmake
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
└── tests
```

The `/CMakeLists.txt` file contains

```
project(custom_webkit)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 17)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

The `/src/CMakeLists.txt` file contains

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS REQUIRED
    Core
    Widgets
    WebKit
    WebKitWidgets
    WebView
    PrintSupport
    Quick
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::WebKit
    Qt5::WebKitWidgets
    Qt5::WebView
    Qt5::PrintSupport
    Qt5::Quick
)
```

The `/platforms/windows.cmake` file contains

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

set(Qt5_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5)
set(Qt5Core_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core)
set(Qt5Gui_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui)
set(Qt5Widgets_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Widgets)
set(Qt5WebKit_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5WebKit)
set(Qt5WebKitWidgets_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5WebKitWidgets)
set(Qt5WebView_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5WebView)
set(Qt5PrintSupport_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5PrintSupport)
set(Qt5Network_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Network)
set(Qt5Concurrent_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Concurrent)
set(Qt5DBus_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5DBus)
set(Qt5Qml_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Qml)
set(Qt5Quick_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Quick)
set(Qt5QuickWidgets_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5QuickWidgets)
set(Qt5Xml_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Xml)
```

The `/src/main.cpp` file contains

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebView>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string uri = "http://testing.example.lan/";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView *view = new QWebView();

    view->resize(800,600);
    view->load(QUrl(QString::fromStdString(uri)));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Building for Linux works fine as you can see here

```
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$ rm -rf ./*
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$
```

Here is the part of the generated `/build/src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/build.make` file that is relevant to the problem. In this case it all looks fine.

```
[...]
../bin/custom_webkit: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/main.cpp.o
../bin/custom_webkit: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/custom_webkit_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
../bin/custom_webkit: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/build.make
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.212.0
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebView.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5.212.0
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.12.2
../bin/custom_webkit: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/link.txt
[...]
```

Here running `make` for Linux

```
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target custom_webkit_autogen
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target custom_webkit
[ 25%] Built target custom_webkit_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target custom_webkit
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/custom_webkit_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/custom_webkit
[100%] Built target custom_webkit
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$
```

The executable works as expected.
Below is the process I follow to build for Windows without success.
This first stage appears to have no errors.

```
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$ rm -rf ./*
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/windows.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$
```

But the part of the generated `/build/src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/build.make` file that is relevant to the problem, in this case you see all the `XXX-NOTFOUND`.

```
[...]
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/main.cpp.obj
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/custom_webkit_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/build.make
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::WebKitWidgets-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::WebView-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::PrintSupport-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::WebKit-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::Quick-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::Qml-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::Network-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::Widgets-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::Gui-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::Core-NOTFOUND
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/linklibs.rsp
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/objects1.rsp
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/link.txt
[...]
```

Then `make` fails with the following error.

```
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target custom_webkit_autogen
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target custom_webkit
[ 25%] Built target custom_webkit_autogen
src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/build.make:99: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:91: src/CMakeFiles/custom_webkit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
user@desktop:~/Development/Projects/cpp/webkit/build$
```

Line 99 is this

```
../bin/custom_webkit.exe: Qt5::WebKitWidgets-NOTFOUND
```

Some more information about my system.

```
root@desktop:~# dpkg -l | grep webkit
ii  libkf5webkit5:amd64                           5.60.0a-0ubuntu1~ubuntu19.04~ppa1           amd64        KDE Integration for QtWebKit.
ii  libqt5webkit5:amd64                           5.212.0~alpha2-22                           amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5webkit5-dev:amd64                       5.212.0~alpha2-22                           amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - development files
ii  libqtwebkit-dev                               2.3.2-0ubuntu13                             amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - development files
ii  libqtwebkit4:amd64                            2.3.2-0ubuntu13                             amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64                    2.24.2-0ubuntu0.19.04.1                     amd64        Web content engine library for GTK
ii  qml-module-qtwebkit:amd64                     5.212.0~alpha2-22                           amd64        Qt WebKit QML module

root@desktop:~# dpkg -l | grep mingw
ii  binutils-mingw-w64-i686                       2.32-7ubuntu4+8.3ubuntu2                    amd64        Cross-binutils for Win32 (x86) using MinGW-w64
ii  binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64                     2.32-7ubuntu4+8.3ubuntu2                    amd64        Cross-binutils for Win64 (x64) using MinGW-w64
ii  g++-mingw-w64                                 8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   all          GNU C++ compiler for MinGW-w64
ii  g++-mingw-w64-i686                            8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   amd64        GNU C++ compiler for MinGW-w64 targeting Win32
ii  g++-mingw-w64-x86-64                          8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   amd64        GNU C++ compiler for MinGW-w64 targeting Win64
ii  gcc-mingw-w64                                 8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   all          GNU C compiler for MinGW-w64
ii  gcc-mingw-w64-base                            8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   amd64        GNU Compiler Collection for MinGW-w64 (base package)
ii  gcc-mingw-w64-i686                            8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   amd64        GNU C compiler for MinGW-w64 targeting Win32
ii  gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64                          8.3.0-6ubuntu1+21.1build2                   amd64        GNU C compiler for MinGW-w64 targeting Win64
ii  mingw-w64                                     6.0.0-3                                     all          Development environment targeting 32- and 64-bit Windows
ii  mingw-w64-common                              6.0.0-3                                     all          Common files for Mingw-w64
ii  mingw-w64-i686-dev                            6.0.0-3                                     all          Development files for MinGW-w64 targeting Win32
ii  mingw-w64-tools                               6.0.0-3                                     amd64        Development tools for 32- and 64-bit Windows
ii  mingw-w64-x86-64-dev                          6.0.0-3                                     all          Development files for MinGW-w64 targeting Win64

root@desktop:~# dpkg -l | grep qt5
ii  kde-style-oxygen-qt5                          4:5.16.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu19.04~ppa1          amd64        Qt decoration for the Oxygen desktop theme
ii  kde-style-qtcurve-qt5:amd64                   1.9-2build3                                 amd64        QtCurve widget style for applications based on Qt 5.x
ii  libaccounts-qt5-1:amd64                       1.15+17.04.20161104.1-0ubuntu1              amd64        QT library for single sign on
ii  libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64                       0.9.3+16.04.20160218-1ubuntu1               amd64        Qt implementation of the DBusMenu protocol
ii  libpackagekitqt5-1:amd64                      1.0.1-1                                     amd64        Library for accessing PackageKit using Qt5
ii  libphonon4qt5-4:amd64                         4:4.10.2-1                                  amd64        multimedia framework from KDE using Qt 5 - core library
ii  libpolkit-qt5-1-1:amd64                       0.112.0-6                                   amd64        PolicyKit-qt5-1 library
ii  libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64                        0.74.0-0ubuntu1.2                           amd64        PDF rendering library (Qt 5 based shared library)
ii  libqca-qt5-2:amd64                            2.1.3-2ubuntu2                              amd64        libraries for the Qt Cryptographic Architecture
ii  libqca-qt5-2-plugins:amd64                    2.1.3-2ubuntu2                              amd64        QCA plugins for libqca2
ii  libqt5concurrent5:amd64                       5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 concurrent module
ii  libqt5core5a:amd64                            5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 core module
ii  libqt5dbus5:amd64                             5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 D-Bus module
ii  libqt5designer5:amd64                         5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 designer module
ii  libqt5designercomponents5:amd64               5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Designer components module
ii  libqt5gui5:amd64                              5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 GUI module
ii  libqt5help5:amd64                             5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 help module
ii  libqt5hunspellinputmethod5:amd64              5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt virtual keyboard - helper library for Hunspell input method
ii  libqt5multimedia5:amd64                       5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia module
ii  libqt5multimedia5-plugins:amd64               5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia module plugins
ii  libqt5multimediagsttools5:amd64               5.12.2-1                                    amd64        GStreamer tools for  Qt 5 Multimedia module
ii  libqt5multimediaquick5:amd64                  5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia Quick module
ii  libqt5multimediawidgets5:amd64                5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia Widgets module
ii  libqt5network5:amd64                          5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 network module
ii  libqt5networkauth5:amd64                      5.12.2-1                                    amd64        online account access for Qt apps - Library
ii  libqt5opengl5:amd64                           5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL module
ii  libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64                       5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL library development files
ii  libqt5positioning5:amd64                      5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt Positioning module
ii  libqt5printsupport5:amd64                     5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 print support module
ii  libqt5qml5:amd64                              5.12.2-2                                    amd64        Qt 5 QML module
ii  libqt5quick5:amd64                            5.12.2-2                                    amd64        Qt 5 Quick library
ii  libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64                  5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt 5 Quick Controls 2 library
ii  libqt5quickparticles5:amd64                   5.12.2-2                                    amd64        Qt 5 Quick particles module
ii  libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64                 5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt 5 Quick Templates 2 library
ii  libqt5quicktest5:amd64                        5.12.2-2                                    amd64        Qt 5 Quick Test library
ii  libqt5quickwidgets5:amd64                     5.12.2-2                                    amd64        Qt 5 Quick Widgets library
ii  libqt5script5:amd64                           5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt 5 script module
ii  libqt5scripttools5:amd64                      5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt 5 script tools module
ii  libqt5sensors5:amd64                          5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt Sensors module
ii  libqt5serialport5:amd64                       5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 serial port support
ii  libqt5sql5:amd64                              5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 SQL module
ii  libqt5sql5-mysql:amd64                        5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 MySQL database driver
ii  libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64                       5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libqt5svg5:amd64                              5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 SVG module
ii  libqt5test5:amd64                             5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 test module
ii  libqt5texttospeech5:amd64                     5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Speech library for Qt - libraries
ii  libqt5virtualkeyboard5:amd64                  5.12.2+dfsg-1                               amd64        Qt virtual keyboard - public shared library
ii  libqt5waylandclient5:amd64                    5.12.2-1                                    amd64        QtWayland client library
ii  libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64                5.12.2-1                                    amd64        QtWayland compositor library
ii  libqt5webchannel5:amd64                       5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Web communication library for Qt
ii  libqt5webengine-data                          5.12.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1                        all          Web content engine library for Qt - Data
ii  libqt5webengine5:amd64                        5.12.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1                        amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5webenginecore5:amd64                    5.12.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1                        amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - Core
ii  libqt5webenginewidgets5:amd64                 5.12.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1                        amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - Widget
ii  libqt5webkit5:amd64                           5.212.0~alpha2-22                           amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5webkit5-dev:amd64                       5.212.0~alpha2-22                           amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - development files
ii  libqt5webview5:amd64                          5.12.2-1                                    amd64        display web content in a QML application - Library
ii  libqt5webview5-dev:amd64                      5.12.2-1                                    amd64        display web content in a QML application - Development Files
ii  libqt5widgets5:amd64                          5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 widgets module
ii  libqt5x11extras5:amd64                        5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 X11 extras
ii  libqt5xml5:amd64                              5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 XML module
ii  libqt5xmlpatterns5:amd64                      5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 XML patterns module
ii  libreoffice-qt5                               1:6.2.5-0ubuntu0.19.04.1                    amd64        office productivity suite -- Qt 5 integration
ii  libsignon-qt5-1:amd64                         8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu1                amd64        Single Sign On framework
ii  phonon4qt5:amd64                              4:4.10.2-1                                  amd64        multimedia framework from KDE using Qt 5 - metapackage
ii  phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer:amd64            4:4.9.0-1                                   amd64        Phonon Qt5 GStreamer 1.0 backend
ii  python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5                   5.12.1+dfsg-1                               amd64        D-Bus Qt main loop support for Python 3
ii  python3-pyqt5                                 5.12.1+dfsg-1                               amd64        Python 3 bindings for Qt5
ii  qdbus-qt5                                     5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 D-Bus tool
ii  qdoc-qt5                                      5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 qdoc tool
ii  qt5-assistant                                 5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Assistant
ii  qt5-default:amd64                             5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 development defaults package
ii  qt5-doc                                       5.11.3-1                                    all          Qt 5 API Documentation
ii  qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64                   5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 GTK+ 3 platform theme
ii  qt5-image-formats-plugins:amd64               5.12.2-1                                    amd64        Qt 5 Image Formats module
ii  qt5-qmake:amd64                               5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool
ii  qt5-qmake-bin                                 5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool — binary file
ii  qt5-qmltooling-plugins:amd64                  5.12.2-2                                    amd64        Qt 5 qmltooling plugins
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

just an advice:

use Webengine, not deprecated webkit.

Webengine is a Chromium based web component, and works in windows (only visual studio) and Linux.

The only "problem" is that dosen't works in android/iOS. Mingw is not suported because Chromium requeriments

You can use the Visuastudio 2019 Community Edition, or just Windows 10 SDK (that includes the same command line compiler), and then, precompiled Qt distributions downloaded from official qt site.

I was thinking is a linux crosscompiler, but now, I using an small windows laptop as a secondary compiler engine...with a teamviewer local connection and I'm saving A LOT OF TIME.

May be you need an automated software compilation system...then, you will spend a lot of time in "small problems" like this ... and Qt releases new versions each 2 months ...

Comment: Thanks for you answer it helps. Webengine compiles excellent on Linux but fails the same exactly way to compile for Windows. I do not develop anything on a Windows OS and personally dislike VS and IDEs in general. I want to have full control on every step of the development process and dislike delays of VS and IDEs, not to mention security. But I will give it a try for just a fallback until I find the proper way to do it on Linux. While Webengine is more up-to-date, I still don’t know what is wrong with the above setup on my post.

Comment: I undertand you, but, sometimes, time is money. MingW is not supported for Chromium builds. MSVC is the native compiler for windows, so I think is the best solution. Using prebuild Qt can save you a lot of time, and you don't need to install full IDE, just windows 10 SDK

Comment: Do you have an official link where I can download prebuild Qt ? because this started giving me a headache. I agree 100% that time is money, and it seems that Windows are not the environment to work on when you don't have time to spend is it ...

Comment: Cjhoose LGPL edition here:   https://www.qt.io/download. Then , using Qt online installer you chan choose your compiler and versions (for example VS217 64 bits)